# How do create a button using Sprite Kit and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am currently working on a platforming game for iOS. I would like to be able to move my character left or right by the press of a button. How is it that I can create a button? Do I use `UIKit` or an `SKNode`?

If possible I would like to know both methods or the most efficient.

Thanks in advance!!!!

-Matt A.

Answer (score 3):

The common strategy to handle user press event is using system provided `func touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event`:

```
//add trigger node into your scene
let triggerNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTextureAtlas(named: "scenery.atlas").textureNamed(soundImg))
triggerNode.name = "TriggerNodeName"
triggerNode.zPosition = 10
addChild(triggerNode)

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchNode = atPoint(location)
        print("\(touchNode.name)")

        if touchNode.name == "TriggerNodeName"{
            //write your logic here
            ...
            return
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is this in the GameScene?

Comment: yep, balabalabala

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Fantastic! One last question how do I stop the action once the user has stopped pressing?

Comment: I know it has something to do with "touchesEnd"

Comment: what type of press you mean? if it's just normal `touchUpInside`,  `touchBegan` is enough, you do not to need to handle touch end case

Comment: if you mean continuous press which has three status (before press, pressing, after press),  you can implement your logic with another three atomic system provided functions: `touchesCancelled(_:with:)`,`touchesEnded(_:with:)`,`touchesMoved(_:with:)`

Comment: Well, I'm new to Swift to let me tell you my situation and you can decide which one works best.

Comment: I would like the user to press the button and my character would move until the user releases his/her press. I can press the button, but my player wont stop moving. Here is a piece from one of my functions:                                         if (currentDirection == .left) {
            
            thePlayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.position.x - currentSpeed, y: self.position.y)

Comment: Oh, I figured it out I used touchesEnded to tell my player to stop. Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:
When touchesBegan my player would go left. Then I used touchesEnded to tell my player to stop.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches{
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let touchNode = atPoint(location)
            print("\(touchNode.name)")

            if touchNode.name == "Button"{
                //write your logic here
                thePlayer.goLeft()
                print("Pressed!")
            }
        }


    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        for touch in touches{
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let touchNode = atPoint(location)
            print("\(touchNode.name)")

            if touchNode.name == "Button"{
                //write your logic here
                thePlayer.stop()
                print("Pressed!")
            }
        }


    }
```